# Convert a masive amount to files to pdf

Tags: sql, database, file, pdf

I'm designing a  website for a small company and they want a database of documents where a user can search for policies. They hand me a rar with over 800 documents all within folders and with different files formats (for example a policy is divided into 3 jpeg files or a single .doc document). I trying to find a way to convert all these files to a pdf format without doing it manually in order to make a SQL database. someone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking into Apache POI. You could write a module to automate the process and convert all of them into PDFs.

https://poi.apache.org/